# Maximization with the Dual using the Simplex Method.

Tags: optimization, duality-theorems, simplex

I have an exam in a few hours. I need to understand the solution to the following question

Find the Maximal to the the following $2 x_1 + 3  x_2$ is the objective function.

The constraints are

$4x_1 + 3x_2 ≤ 600;$

$x_1 + x_2 ≤ 160;$

$3x_1 + 7 x_2 ≤ 840;$

$x_1,x_2≥0.$

Also the answer should be in the "Dual". If its possible please do it in the Algebraic method. If not I would just like the solution using the tableau method and how do you arrive to the solution.(PS: Any help would be great. )

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to solve this with the simplex method (tableau method) the inequalities of the contraints should be equalities. So you have to use slack variables.

$$4x_1+3x_2 \leq 600$$
$$x_1+x_2 \leq 160$$
$$3x_1+7x_2 \leq 840$$
$$x_1,x_2 \geq 0$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$4x_1+3x_2 +x_3 = 600$$
$$x_1+x_2 +x_4 =160$$
$$3x_1+7x_2 +x_5= 840$$
$$x_1,x_2,x_3, x_4, x_5 \geq 0$$

Then can you continue by creating the tableau?

As regards the Algebraic method:

Draw the $x_1$-axis and the $x_2$-axis. Then from the first contraint you get:

$4x_1+3x_2 \leq 600 : \text{ when } x_1=0 \Rightarrow x_2=200 \text{ and  when } x_2=0 \Rightarrow x_1=150$. So you get the line as below, and since it is $\leq 600$ the feasible region is below this line. 
[image]
Can you do this for the other contraints and find the solution? You should also keep in mind that $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$